# Cannot start WSL (using Win11 22H2)

Tags: windows-update, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11, wsl2, docker-for-windows

I think this started happening after I updated my Windows 11. Current version is Windows 11, Version 22H2 (OS Build 22623.1037).

Initially, my Docker Desktop also stopped working, but I uninstalled it to focus on WSL only.

What I tried:

- `wsl -l -v` --> no response
- Opening Ubuntu 20.04 icon from the start menu --> no response.
  WSL (using WSL2) is completely unresponsive, and so is my Docker Desktop.

Obviously, I'm expecting WSL to show the shell prompt screen, but it's completely unresponsive!

Comment: Edit your question to I indicate if the required optional Windows features for WSL2 are installed

Answer (score 0):

WSL did change quite substantially in Windows 11 22H2, so the upgrade could be a  factor.  The good news for troubleshooting this, at least, is that there are now two different "types" of WSL installation.  If one is having an issue, then perhaps switching to the other may resolve.  The two "types" are:

- WSL as a Windows feature -- This is the original (now old) way that WSL was delivered.  This is known as the "In-box" version of WSL, since it "comes with Windows" and just has to be enabled.
- WSL as a Store (UWP) app -- This is the new method of installing WSL.  It's been in Preview since October 2021, but with Windows 11 22H2, it became the official way of installing new WSL releases.  A `wsl --update` in Windows 11 22H2 should (in my experience) switch from the in-box version to the Store version.  More accurately, both are enabled, but the Store version takes priority.

Both versions still require the "Virtual Machine Platform" feature (or Hyper-V) to be enabled in Windows in order to provide WSL2 functionality.  It would be useful to verify, via the *Turn Windows features on or off* settings, that the VMP is enabled. If not, enable it and reboot.  It's unlikely, IMHO, that it is disabled, since you would normally receive an error message when starting a WSL2 distribution (rather than unresponsiveness).  Still worth double-checking though.

The easiest way to determine if you are using the In-box or Store/App, if it is working, would be to check the Start menu for "Windows Subsystem for Linux".  If present, that would indicate the Store version.  If absent, the in-box.

Depending on the results:

- If you find you are using the in-box version, try installing the Store version.  You can do that from the [Microsoft Store page](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) directly.

  A reboot is advisable, especially in your case.

  Then check `wsl --version`.  If it reports component versions, then the WSL App is installed.  See if you can launch your distribution or run `wsl -l -v` at that point.
- If you are using the Store/App version, try uninstalling it.  This can be done simply by searching the Start menu for "Windows Subsystem for Linux", right-clicking, and *Uninstall*.  It can also be done through the normal *Add or remove programs* settings.

  After uninstalling, confirm in *Turn Windows features on or off* that the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" feature is enabled, reboot, and try to launch your distribution and run `wsl -l -v`.

  If so, you may want to try to reinstall the Store version again at that point to see if a simple "uninstall/reinstall" solved the issue.

---

Other troubleshooting steps:

- With the Store version installed, try running in the new "Safe mode".  To do so, create or edit, in your *Windows* user profile directory, `.wslconfig` with the following:

  ```
  [wsl2]
  safeMode = true
  ```

  Try to run it again.
- Run the following in PowerShell:

  ```
  Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\
  ```

  Look for any "oddness" in here, which I know is tough to quantify since you don't have a known "good state".  However, an obvious example of a potential problem would be garbled characters in a directory or distribution name.
- Uninstall everything possible (other than the distribution) and reinstall.  That includes uninstalling the WSL Store App and turning off the *Windows Subsystem for Linux* and *Virtual Machine Platform* features.

  Turning back on each component individually (starting with VMP, then WSL feature) might give you some indication of a deeper issue.  Watch carefully during any reboots for messages pertaining to the component installation.
- In the worst case (but not yet, let's keep troubleshooting for a bit, if needed) you might try backing up and deleting the existing WSL registry entries found there.  You can back up the WSL2 disk image itself from the directory specified in the `BasePath` property, under the `LocalState` directory there.  The filename for WSL2 images should always (currently) be `ext4.vhdx`.  That image can be restored if and when you get the Subsystem itself back to a working state.

Comment: I will go through it this evening and report back

Comment: (1) **Virtual Machine Platform** is confirmed to be already enabled on my machine under *Turn Windows features on or off*.  (2) I was able to see **Windows Subsystem for Linux** at Start Menu -- I have store version (3) wsl outputs can be seen at https://imgur.com/a/FE56H2H; I don't see `.wslconfig` file at my home directory - what would this mean? Last bullet point might really be very useful tip for me.  I might save the `.vhdx` file and uninstall store version.  I will go through last three bullets tomorrow.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but somewhat related to the topic of the issue: where is a good place to report any issues I have with Windows 11? I am getting Windows 11 through *Windows Insider Program* but not sure where to report any issues I have with the *Previews*.  (I am seeing weird behaviours on my laptop)

Comment: @k8yun Not sure - Maybe [here](https://insider.windows.com/feedback)?

Comment: @k8yun *"I don't see .wslconfig file at my home directory - what would this mean?"* -- Normal.  It doesn't exist by default, so you just create it if needed.

Comment: thanks for additional pointers.  I've uninstalled gWSL Preview and also uninstalled the WSL (after running out of all my options).  I will see if I can recover my Windows PC.